# How do i make a function run every 30 seconds or something?

Tags: php, html, loops, web

Hi im currently making my background images appear randomly. But now i want it to change the images every 30 or 40 seconds. Right now my code looks like this:

```
#background{
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100px;
<?php
  $count = rand(1, 8);
  $hello = "background: url('img/backImg/". $count ."') center center;"; 
  echo ($hello);
?>
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:   #d8d8d8;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

So i want the `$count` string to take a random number every 30 seconds.

Comment: You need ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ or something unrelated to php.

Comment: You need ajax or javascript of jquery

Comment: You can't do that with PHP on the server.  You need to send javascript code that runs inside the browser.

Comment: @bozdoz w3schools is a terrible resource. I recommend jQuery's own tutorial.

Comment: @JanDvorak Stop being pretentious.

Comment: @bozdoz it's not about being pretentious. It's that W3Schools hold outright wrong information. Do you want me to list it here?

Comment: I've seen the list; I'm just not impressed, @JanDvorak.  I think StackOverflow could be a better site if people could stop being haters.

Comment: @bozdoz I think you haven't seen the right list, then. Hold on, writing down misinformation _only_ from that specific tutorial you have linked. And if you call me a hater because I hate outright misinformation and abudance of bad practices, then sure call be a hater.

Comment: @bozdoz "AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages." - sure, the majority of Javascript application use AJAX, but it's not AJAX per se that allows dynamisation. The list of main benefits of AJAX lists the main benefits of javascript. Relatively minor sin.

Comment: @bozdoz "AJAX is based on internet standards, and uses a combination of: ... CSS," - CSS has nothing to do with AJAX, and you shouldn't create new CSS in response to AJAX requests. "... XML (often used as the format for transferring data)" - This might have been true in the prehistoric ages, but normally you use JSON. I haven't seen XML as an AJAX request/response in ages, if ever. Sure, it's what the acronym says, but this doesn't make it any less of a sin. Sure, you could argue that it shouldn't make the readers use XML. I doubt that it's true, but here you go: not outright misinformation.

Comment: @bozdoz "AJAX applications are browser- and platform-independent!" - unlike traditional static HTML pages, sure. Oh and those ultramodern WebGL multiplayer real-time games don't actually use AJAX (or do they?). AJAX does, in no way, ensure platform independence (the browser is a major part of the platform, by the way). The closest sentence to this might be "AJAX does not introduce platform dependency" but then it doesn't deserve the exclamation mark, its border, or the lightbulb. Perhaps not even a paragraph of its own. This sentence at its current form is useless at best.

Comment: @bozdoz "To handle all modern browsers, including IE5 and IE6" -- It's nice of them to include information about how to preserve compatibility with age old browsers - even if 99% developers aren't going to support, or even _see_, IE6. Perhaps they shouldn't do it as a part of their basic tutorial, but it's still not neccessarily a sin. In this sentence they called IE5 a modern browser, however. Ew. Sure, go ahead, call me a hater. I still think they should have said "_and_ IE5 and IE6". Or better yet, drop the compatibility fix altogether. But here you go: minor sin.

Comment: "GET is simpler and faster than POST, and can be used in most cases." - WRONG! GET is in no way faster than POST, unless you count the three byte difference between a question mark and a pair of newlines. It is not simpler either, unless you count as simplification that you can call a no-arg method instead of a one-arg method by concatenating the data to _another_ method. "POST is more robust and secure than GET" - They are both equally transparent to MITM attacks. All you get is that POST data is not logged by default on the server. Also, the only benefit to robustness is it prevents caching.

Comment: (except on Apple Safari, but that's a different story)

Comment: @bozdoz no information on URL escaping. There should be some.  "Before AJAX, this operation could cause the application to hang or stop." - what operation, again? Page navigation is no way as scary as they make it seem. Synchronous AJAX causes freezes, but that wasn't "before AJAX". "Using async=false is not recommended, but for a few small requests this can be ok." - definitely not. The only valid usage of `async=false` is bad design or having to work around some limitation of a badly designed libary. I did notice they do warn against it, however.

Comment: @bozdoz the `readyState` table is wrong. The client does not know when the request was received, nor when the processing has started, nor are they two separate events. MDN states for these two "headers have been received" and "partial content is available". Their descriptions of 0 and 1 don't really say anything either. "When readyState is 4 and status is 200, the response is ready:" - but when the status is 404 or, say, 503, the response needs some more processing? No, it doesn't. The response is already there in either case (even if not particularly useful  in case of a 404).

Comment: @bozdoz In their "using a callback function" example, if `loadXMLdoc` is their abstraction, their abstraction doesn't go far enough. Also, they're swallowing error states. Oh, and they probably should have mentioned `onload` by now. Their autocomplete example is susceptible to race conditions, which they don't even mention, nor include a solution of. I think Google in 2005 did handle that correctly. Also, it doesn't escape the query string. Their autocomplete will ignore everything after an `&`. Oh and `str.length == 0` should be `str === ''`. Also, they have mixed in an ASP and PHP tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) Plugin is a slideshow plugin that supports many different types of transition effects. It supports pause-on-hover, auto-stop, auto-fit, before/after callbacks, click triggers and much more.

You can set `timeout` or `delay` to 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the help of javascript. it will call this function every 30 seconds

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},30000);
function myTimer(){
    // your code to change the background image url 
    // you can do that with $('#background').attr('style',"your css") or  
    // $('#background').css('background-url',"your path") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function counter() {
     randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1; //make random number between 1-8
     $(this).css("background-image", "url('img/backImg/" + randomNumber + ".png')");
     setTimeout("counter()",30000); play function counter after 30s
  });//end the $(document).ready
</script>
</pre>
```

try this code, i hope it help you.

this function start when your page is ready to work, and generate a random number between 1-8, then change your background image and do it a gain after 30s
you just set your Instead the this.